# Integrating HERE Maps Javascript API in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, here-api, react-native-maps

This is a question about the HERE Indoor Maps API for JavaScript. Is there a way to use MapView, create a wrapper, or a package to help load this JS code from the `main.js` file and the `index.html` file into React Native? They do not support React Native and I need to find a way to make it work. Even if you think it is not possible, I would apprciate a comment letting me know.

```
const yourApikey = '';
const indoorMapHrn = '';
const venueId = '';
const drawingId = '';
const showBaseMap = true;
const levelIndex = 1;

const labelTextPreferenceOverride = [
  H.venues.Service2.LABEL_TEXT_PREFERENCE_OVERRIDE.OCCUPANT_NAMES,
  H.venues.Service2.LABEL_TEXT_PREFERENCE_OVERRIDE.SPACE_NAME
]

/**
 * Load and add indoor data on the map.
 *
 * @param  {H.Map} map A HERE Map instance
 * @param  {H.service.Platform} platform A HERE Platform instance
 */
function addVenueToMap(map, platform) {

  const venuesProvider = new H.venues.Provider();

  const venuesService = platform.getVenuesService({ apikey: yourApikey, hrn: indoorMapHrn }, 2);

  venuesService.getMapInfoList().then(mapInfoList => {
    mapInfoList.forEach(mapInfo => {
      console.log("Indoor map id: " + mapInfo.mapId + ", map name: " + mapInfo.mapName);
    });
  });

  venuesService.loadVenue(venueId, { labelTextPreferenceOverride }).then((venue) => {
    venuesProvider.addVenue(venue);
    venuesProvider.setActiveVenue(venue);

    const venueLayer = new H.map.layer.TileLayer(venuesProvider);
    if (showBaseMap) {
      map.addLayer(venueLayer);
    } else {
      map.setBaseLayer(venueLayer);
    }

    map.setCenter(venue.getCenter());

    if (venue.getDrawing(drawingId)) {
      venue.setActiveDrawing(drawingId);
    }

    if (venue.getLevels().length >= levelIndex) {
      venue.setActiveLevelIndex(levelIndex);
    }

    const levelControl = new H.venues.ui.LevelControl(venue);
    ui.addControl('level-control', levelControl);
    const drawingControl = new H.venues.ui.DrawingControl(venue);
    ui.addControl('drawing-control', drawingControl);
  });
}

var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: yourApikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'), defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
  zoom: 18,
  center: { lat: 47.452353, lng: 8.562455 },
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

addVenueToMap(map, platform);
```

This is the index.html file to render the map, I am wondering if maybe I could use a MapView Element from React Native.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Use the HERE Indoor Maps API to load and visualize an indoor map">
        <title>Display an Indoor Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-venues.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../template.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src='../test-credentials.js'></script>
        <style type="text/css">
          .log {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            left: 5px;
            height: 150px;
            width: 250px;
            overflow: scroll;
            background: white;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            font-size: 12px;
          }
          .log-entry {
            padding: 5px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d9e9;
          }
          .log-entry:nth-child(odd) {
              background-color: #e1e7f1;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='demo.js'></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```